# Can I get a post-doc in a different area of math than my PhD?

Tags: phd, mathematics, postdocs

I am in the 4th year of my PhD, and my research area is generalized integral (Henstock integral, Denjoy integral, etc.). I am facing problems concerning the publication in a good journal since my research topic is of interest to specialized audiences. Honestly, it is really hard to be persistent as a researcher on an old topic like generalized integral and if I don't have good publications, then I will not have good opportunities. So, I was thinking to do another PhD on a well-known topic, e.g., Partial Differential Equations, Geometry, etc., and previously, I posted a question regarding the second PhD. However, I did not get satisfactory suggestions. So, now I want to know if it is possible to have a postdoctoral position without any research experience in PDE or Geometry. If not, then what should I do?

Comment: It is impossible to say, since decisions are based on more than one criteria. But it is probably easer to change if you stay closer to your current subfield (another field in Analysis) than if it is very different.

Comment: The best way to get an answer to this question is to apply for some postdoc jobs in the area of interest and see what happens.

Comment: Doing 2 PhDs in mathematics would be very unusual, and I don't know what program would admit you.  It would be better if you do work in other areas before graduating, whether by changing your thesis topic or by working on side projects.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you get such a position in a different field, but the question is: are you qualified for it? If someone wants to hire a postdoc in geometry and there is someone with the requisite expertise, how does your expertise stack up?

You are asking whether it is possible that someone offers you a postdoc position during which you might be allowed to learn what is necessary for the job *while you're being paid for the job*. That seems unlikely.

That said, many departments have positions for postdocs that come with teaching responsibilities, but are otherwise not closely tied to a specific project. You might be able to get one of these, and while there reposition your research. That's possible because your primary responsibility is for teaching, and you have a degree of freedom for whatever else you do during the rest of your time.